# input directly in process.communicate() in subprocess library

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to use both multiline input for command 'cat -' and single line input in 'pwd'.

For that i am trying to get input directly in process.communicate() , I am getting broken pipe error. What shall i replace in the argument passed?

```
command = 'cat -'
stdout_value=''

process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    shell=True)
while True:
    if process.poll() is not None:
    break    
    stdout_value = stdout_value + process.communicate(process.stdin)[0]

print(repr(stdout_value))
```

This code gets error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 67, in <module>
    stdout_value = stdout_value + process.communicate(process.stdin)[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1068, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1687, in _communicate
    input_view = memoryview(self._input)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedWriter'
[vibhcool@localhost try]$ Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: what's the `proc.stdin`?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko it is process.stdin , updated it :P

Comment: `communicate("HELLO".encode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 1):

`process.communicate()` expects string which you have `encoded()` to bytes and it returns bytes which you have to `decode()` to string.

You use `process.stdin` which is not string. It even doesn't have method `read()` to do `process.communicate(process.stdin.read())` (besides using `process.stdin` with the same `process` makes no sense). It could be rather `process.communicate(other_process.stdout.read())` (if you have other process)

Working example - I send text with numbers to command `sort` and it returns text with sorted numbers.

```
input:  3\n2\n5\n-1
output: -1\n2\n3\n5\n
```

Code

```
import subprocess
import shlex

command = 'sort'

process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    shell=True)

stdout_value = ''

while True:
    if process.poll() is not None:
        break
    result = process.communicate("3\n2\n5\n-1".encode('utf-8'))[0]
    stdout_value += result.decode('utf-8')

print(repr(stdout_value))
```